# How to change background color of bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change the background color of one column in bootstrap row.  There will be padding inside row as well. Please refer the below screenshot of requirement.

[image]

```
    <div class="container event-details-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h3 class="event-tag tooltip" tooltip="Click here to copy the event code" @click.stop="copyEvent($event)">#{{event.code}}</h3>
      <UserWidget :repeatEvent="true" :email="event.name" :title="event.duration" :action="goToEvent"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="display:flex;">
      <div class="QnA-Details"></div>
      <div class="Sub-QnA-Details">
        <p>Q&A</p>
        <span>3000</span>
      </div>
      <div class="Form-Details"></div>
      <div class="Sub-Form-Details">
        <p>Forms</p>
        <span>06</span>
      </div>
      <div class="Polls-Details"></div>
      <div class="Sub-Polls-Details">
        <p>Polls</p>
        <span>02</span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="event-actions-wrapper" v-if="!isExpired">
      <ul>
        <li><div class="event-action download tooltip" tooltip="Project event" @click.stop="download"></div></li>
        <li><div class="event-action project tooltip" tooltip="Project event" @click.stop="project"></div></li>
        <li><div class="event-action phone tooltip" tooltip="Project event" @click.stop="phone"></div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

here how is my code inside this model. When I try to change the particular column color padding area does not colored.

[image]

How should I achieve top requirement using this scenario? I used bootstrap, because its needs to be responsive for mobile devices as well.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the area and find out in which <div> or tag the area is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, I set directly background on last column by adding as below:

```
style="background: red;"
```

And it seems to work fine. If it does not by you then probably we are missing some css.

INFO: I just added `background :grey;` on row for the demo

### DEMO:

```css
.row{
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container event-details-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h3 class="event-tag tooltip" tooltip="Click here to copy the event code" @click.stop="copyEvent($event)">#{{event.code}}</h3>
      <UserWidget :repeatEvent="true" :email="event.name" :title="event.duration" :action="goToEvent"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="display:flex;">
      <div class="QnA-Details"></div>
        <div class="Sub-QnA-Details">
          <p>Q&A</p>
          <span>3000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Form-Details"></div>
        <div class="Sub-Form-Details">
          <p>Forms</p>
          <span>06</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Polls-Details"></div>
        <div class="Sub-Polls-Details">
          <p>Polls</p>
          <span>02</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background: red;">
        <div class="event-actions-wrapper" v-if="!isExpired">
          <ul>
            <li><div class="event-action download tooltip" tooltip="Project event" @click.stop="download"></div></li>
            <li><div class="event-action project tooltip" tooltip="Project event" @click.stop="project"></div></li>
            <li><div class="event-action phone tooltip" tooltip="Project event" @click.stop="phone"></div></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: yes its works without using padding inside 'event-details-wrapper' tag. If I use padding padding area doesn't colored.

Comment: @dglumesh Try to set a negative margin equal as the padding you are adding

Comment: And then please update your code with the padding lke this I can reproduice...

Comment: yes that is solution. Other solution I found, I individually put padding to three components and parent component 'overflow: hidden, padding:0px'. Its works too. Thank you @MaxiGui. You gave the path to achieve the requirement.

Comment: @dglumesh you welcome. I pleased that it helps you. Please accept answer

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
<style>
.background {
  padding: 15px;  /* Just an example padding */
  background: lightgrey; /* Just an example color */
  background-clip: padding-box;  
}
</style>
```

It's the `background-clip: border-box;`  the important part here. This is what makes the background color extend to the border of the area you are targeting. You can also make it include the border itself like this:
 `background-clip: border-box;`

And bellow I have added the class `background` to the div:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 background">
  <div class="event-actions-wrapper" v-if="!isExpired">
      <ul>
        <li><div class="event-action download tooltip" tooltip="Project 
        event" @click.stop="download"></div></li>
        <li><div class="event-action project tooltip" tooltip="Project 
        event" @click.stop="project"></div></li>
        <li><div class="event-action phone tooltip" tooltip="Project event" 
        @click.stop="phone"></div></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. '.event-actions-wrapper' padding affect to the end bootstrap column.

Comment: I have updated my reply, maybe this will solve your problem. I would have to inspect to see why the background is not covering the padding.

Comment: I will try this out. Thank you for your answer :)